# How to start your Starcraft II games vs AI immediately?

Tags: starcraft-2

Quite often I'm practicing my build orders vs an AI and it sucks to wait for 10 seconds until the game starts, since I'm the only human player in the Lobby. This hurts especially when you make some mistakes in your build order and want to restart the game quickly.

I create those test matches going on to ARCADE > STANDARD > "MAP NAME" (Automaton LE for example). After that I add the AI and start the game. After that a timer appears that counts down from 10. But I notice that sometimes that timer is only set to 3 seconds. Is there a way to start the game immediately? I suppose there could be something like an offline mode or something.

Edit: Is there a way to restart the game like in every single player RTS game? The rehosting makes everything way harder and annoying.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to [this bnet forum post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/8521563013) it is possible by right clicking the map and choosing "Create offline game".

> There is a way to play offline in "Custom Games". Once you pick your
>   map, right click on it and select "Create offline game". From there,
>   you'll be but into a standard lobby as usual except you won't be able
>   to add any human players to the game.